# Listen to java queue with no consumer ideal

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have to implement efficient way to listen to the java queue where resources should never be ideal if there are any messages into queue.

For example:
I have queue "MessageQueue" and there are 3 consumer are listening to queue, if queue has 5 message then all 3 consumers should pick 3 messages and if any consumer finish with 1st message consumption, it should took another message with no delay and so on..

Also I have to implement prioritization as well, depend on message type.

```
public class Message {

    private int id;
    private String message;
    private String type;

    public Message(int id, String message, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.type = type;
    }
    // all getter setters & toString method
    ....
}
```

Consumer:

```
 public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final Queue<Message> queue;

    public Consumer(Queue<Message> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void consume() {
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Message m = queue.poll();
            if (m != null) {
                System.out.println("Consumer: " + m.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. How should I make sure that no consumer should not ideal when there is message in queue?
2. how should I assign multiple consumer to queue and start them up at a time?
3. how should I prioritize message by type. 
   lets say there is only one consumer, C1 who got an message of type A, if there is another message in queue of type A, it should be proceed first.

Comment: look into using thread-safe ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of Queue

Comment: @faljbour can you please elaborate more?

Comment: if you are not using a thread-safe queue you will have a race condition between all threads (Customer) trying to access the queue since you have multiple customer trying to access the queue.

Comment: Consider using an `Executor` with a `PriorityBlockingQueue`. Then use type and timestamp as the comparator.